# Duda con petición xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Quisiera saber si con XMLHttpRequest o fetch puedo enviar una petición a una url para evaluar un código JavaScript ella, por ejemplo hacer clic sobre un boton

Comment: Utiliza `fetch` que es algo más actual

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Básicamente lo que quiero hacer es enviar una petición a una url y evaluar un código JavaScript ella, quería saber si con XMLHttpRequest, lo puedo hacer,